# Authentication failure event for oauth provider

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have added spring security core and oauth provider in my grails application

My config:

```
// Added by the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'com.oauth.Client'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'com.oauth.AuthorizationCode'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'com.oauth.AccessToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'com.oauth.RefreshToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false

//grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/client/index'

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.auth.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.auth.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.auth.Role'


    grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
            '/oauth/token': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
            '/securedOAuth2Resources/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
            '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter'
    ]


        grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
                '/':                ['permitAll'],
                '/**/**':                ['permitAll'],
                '/index':           ['permitAll'],
                '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
                '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
                '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
                '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
                '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
                '/**/fonts/**':     ['permitAll'],
                '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll'],
                '/**/fonts/**':     ['permitAll'],
                '/oauth/authorize.dispatch':      ["isFullyAuthenticated() and (request.getMethod().equals('GET') or request.getMethod().equals('POST'))"],
                '/oauth/token.dispatch':          ["isFullyAuthenticated() and request.getMethod().equals('POST')"],
        ]

        grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'com.oauth.Client'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'com.oauth.AuthorizationCode'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'com.oauth.AccessToken'
        grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'com.oauth.RefreshToken'
```

When i remove filter chain map spring security go for toss and oauth works fine but when is add chain map oauth doesnt work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I figured out that oauth and spring security plugin does not work together in grails 2.4.0.